# download file from remote location

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download

Hey i am in atrouble please help me out.i want to download file from other website to on my location and i used code below

```
Dim wc As New System.Net.WebClient
wc.DownloadFile(pathUrl, fileName)
```

PathUrl,fileName both are correct m 100% sure.

after execution of these 2 line my browser progress-bar goes in to wait state like something is retrieving.but file not download any where.what should i do next?

Comment: Yea, Kim's right. Everyone here is contributing for free, and you could at least accept the answers you think are best for your question. This will increase answerer's and your reputation too!!

Comment: What browser progress bar? You're using a `WebClient` to download it, not your browser. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to leave a comment so:

@AZHAR, the file save location is the second parameter. In your example it is `fileName`, in NiL's example it is `"uploads/myPath.doc"`

If you use `wc.DownloadFileAsync`, make sure to include an `AsyncCompletedEventHandler` so you know when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the correctness of what you did, relatively to your goal (I don't mean the code is incorrect, as it is syntactically correct otherwise it won't compile).

If you want to retrieve a file from a remote location and save it to your local machine, this is surely the worst way!!!!

If, instead, you want to download the file onto your **server**, then your problem is *patience* :)

I mean, the `DownloadFile` method is blocking and can take even hours if you are trying to download something a bluray ripped film or a Linux ISO, no matter how *fast* is your server.

You could think about using an asynchronous job in this case...

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote did download the file, I tested it and it surely download it

the usage of the DownloadFunction is as follows:

```
wc.DownloadFile("http://www.domaine.com/uploads/file.doc", "uploads/myPath.doc");
```

If you are trying to download a big file you can use :

```
wc.DownloadFileAsync
```

and it is the same

Comment: can you tell me where downloaded file will be saved?